# Accessing the name of a private-inherited class from a subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

The following code fails to compile with this error with g++ and a similar error with clang.

```
main.cpp:16:19: error: 'QByteArray' is a private member of 'QByteArray'
        Container2(const QByteArray &ba);
                         ^
main.cpp:3:18: note: constrained by private inheritance here
class Container1:private QByteArray
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../edge-clang/qt5/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:167:21: note: member is declared here
class Q_CORE_EXPORT QByteArray
                    ^
main.cpp:18:30: error: 'QByteArray' is a private member of 'QByteArray'
Container2::Container2(const QByteArray &ba):Container1(ba){}
                             ^
main.cpp:3:18: note: constrained by private inheritance here
class Container1:private QByteArray
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../edge-clang/qt5/include/QtCore/qbytearray.h:167:21: note: member is declared here
class Q_CORE_EXPORT QByteArray
                    ^
```

I don't understand why this is not allowed for Container2 to inherit Container1 and initialize it through a public constructor, even though the inheritance of QByteArray is private.

```
#include <QByteArray>

class Container1:private QByteArray
{
public: 
    Container1() {}
    Container1(const QByteArray &ba);
};

Container1::Container1(const QByteArray &ba):QByteArray(ba){}

class Container2:public Container1
{
public:
    Container2() {}
    Container2(const QByteArray &ba);
};
Container2::Container2(const QByteArray &ba):Container1(ba){}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    QByteArray ba;
    Container1 c1(ba);
    Container2 c2(ba);
}
```

Comment: What is the defn of `QByteArray`? Does it have public ctor?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4aa086189405d1ad

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Add a `class C : public B` with a constructor taking `A` ;)

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/877007ccf3972db1 wheeee

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so this looks like the injected-class-name of `A` is leaking all the way through to `C`... But I wonder why that is the case.

Comment: @Quentin: Yep that's why. Well I don't think private inheritance hides names, it just makes them inaccessible. [The same happens with private members](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c2e3a74932bc1d2). It does seem pretty stupid on the face of it, but there's probably a good reason.

Comment: I upvoted this question (I was once hit by a similar error), but the title is horrible. Please try to come up with more specific question titles, and don't repeat tag names in titles.

Comment: In all the excitement I didn't even notice that, but @Christian is absolutely right.

Answer (score 38):

This is a great bug!

In the context of `C`, "`A`" means "the *injected-class-name* `A` that I get from my base".
You could think of it as `C::B::A`.
Of course, that base is inaccessible due to private inheritance:

```
class A {};

class B : private A {
public:
   B() {}
   B(const A&) {}  
};

class C : public B {
public:
   C(const A&) {}
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b(a);
   C c(a);
}

// main.cpp:11:13: error: 'class A A::A' is inaccessible within this context
//      C(const A&) {}
//              ^
// main.cpp:1:9: note: declared here
//  class A {};
//        ^
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6687cab8caa05f2))

You can fix this by calling it `::A`, taking a more indirect route to actually name the exact same type:

```
class A {};

class B : private A {
public:
   B() {}
   B(const A&) {}  
};

class C : public B {
public:
   C(const ::A&) {}
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b(a);
   C c(a);
}

// OK
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46b1fd5014667c20))

---

As an aside, the exact same logic applies to `private`ly inherited member variables:

```
int x = 1;

class A
{
private:
   int x = 2;
};

class B : A {
public:
   B() { int y = x; }
};

int main()
{
   A a;
   B b(a);
}

// main.cpp: In constructor 'B::B()':
// main.cpp:11:17: error: 'int A::x' is private within this context
//    B() { int y = x; }
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c2e3a74932bc1d2))

It all does seem pretty stupid on the face of it, but there's probably a good reason.

---

In your case, then:

```
Container2(const ::QByteArray &ba);
```

Comment: Cute.  Very cute.

Comment: Thanks very much that explains it.

Comment: The live demos are a great way to illustrate. Please do more of this!

Comment: @Galen: I do it on almost every post I write of this kind ;)

Comment: So the forever-deadpan LRiO *can* be amused by sufficiently unexpected name lookup bugs :>

Comment: I don't think it is stupid. Let's say I have a public Q and a private Q that's part of some class. Within the class, if you try to access an unqualified Q, you'd get the private one. Should the compiler ignore something being private because there happens to be something else that's public with the same (well, same human readable) name?

Comment: "It all does seem pretty stupid on the face of it, but there's probably a good reason." The reason: name lookup always takes place before access control. Means that changing a member from private to public won't quietly change the meaning of your program (e.g. in your second example, one day it went from reading `::x` to `A::x`).

Comment: @Barry: Yes what I mean is there's probably a good reason for that to be true

Comment: @iheanyi: I said it _seems_ stupid "on the face of it"  ;)

Comment: I disagree with the statement "This is a great bug!". As stated later in the answer, "(...) there's probably a good reason."