# why this definition of a derived class is illegal?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance

Why the derived class Derived_from_Private is illegal?
i noticed the member function has an reference to Base, but why it cannot have an reference to Base class?

```
class Base {
public:
  void pub_mem(); // public member
protected:
  int prot_mem; // protected member
private:
  char priv_mem; // private member
};

struct Pub_Derv : public Base {
  // legal
  void memfcn(Base &b) { b = *this; }
};

struct Priv_Derv : private Base {
  // legal
  void memfcn(Base &b) { b = *this; }
};

struct Prot_Derv : protected Base {
  // legal
  void memfcn(Base &b) { b = *this; }
};

struct Derived_from_Public : public Pub_Derv {
  // legal
  void memfcn(Base &b) { b = *this; }
};

struct Derived_from_Private : public Priv_Derv {
  // illegal
  void memfcn(Base &b) { b = *this; }
};

struct Derived_from_Protected : public Prot_Derv {
  // legal
  void memfcn(Base &b) { b = *this; }
};
```

Comment: What are your understanding of the keywords protected and private and in which context?

Comment: With private inheritance there is no implicit conversion to base class (you have to use a cast)

Answer (score 3):

The expression

```
b = *this;
```

needs to invoke an implicit conversion from `*this` to an lvalue of type `Base` in order to call the implicitly declared `Base::operator=(const Base&)`. This conversion goes through the path `Derived_from_Private -> Priv_Derv -> Base`. Since `Priv_Derv` has `Base` as a private base, `Derived_from_Private` does not have access to the second link.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the assignment. the compiler will give me an error as long as i pass an Base as a parameter.

Comment: @JingleiRuan Ah, that's true. The answer xskxzr provided is correct. But you can work around it by using `::Base`.

Answer (score 2):

`Priv_Derv` inherits privately `Base`.  This means that only the class itself knows that it's also a `Base` and only the member functions of `Priv_Derv` can use members of `Base`.

You can later let `Derived_from_Private` inherit publicly from `Priv_Derv`.  It's legal. But unfortunately, due to the former private inheritance, it's as if  `Derived_from_Private` doesn't have `Base` as base class.

Therefore your member function will fail to compile:

```
    void memfcn(Base &b) { b = *this; }
```

`*this` is a `Derived_from_Private`,  but it's illegal to convert it to a `Base` class, because there is no known relation with that class due to the private inheritance.

Comment: But i am not using members of Base. Even if i do not assign *this to Base, as long as i have a parameter of Base (reference or a copy) the compiler gives me an error.

Comment: @JingleiRuan interesting ! It seems that the private inheritance affects the unqualified name lookup. Use ::Base instead of Base to refer explicitly to the right (here global) namespace and it will compile.

Comment: @JingleiRuan yes, that's it ! and it seems to be a compiler bug according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41595470/3723423 But this compiler issue does not affect the validity of my initial answer. You'll see that the :: workaround will compile with an empty body, but fail as soon as you try the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance can provide both **subtyping** and **structural extension**.

When you inherits privately from a base class you have no subtyping, only structural extension. Then (in your problematic case) when you write `b = *this` alas `*this` is **not** of the type `Base` because you have used private inheritance of it.

Private inheritance is usually used (that doesn't mean it's a good practice) to easily construct very simple composition (**has a** base, but not **is a** base).

Comment: Actually, as long as i use a Base as a parameter. the compiler gives an error.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: struct Derived_from_Private : public Priv_Derv {
  // illegal
  void memfcn(Base &b) {   }
};     this is illegal too!!!! why???

Comment: In that case compiler think your are talking about the private base class `Base` then complains, if you want to talk about the type defined at global scope write `::Base`.

Answer (score 0):

A name of a class is inserted into the scope of itself as a public member. This is so-called [*injected-class-name*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name). Name lookup for `Base` in the derived class `Derived_from_Private` will find its injected-class-name instead of the normal one. Because the injected-class-name of `Base` is treated as a public member of `Base`, thus is treated as a private number of `Priv_Derv`, it is inaccessible in `Derived_from_Private`.

Quoted from [[class.access.spec] paragraph 5](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.access.spec#5):

> [ *Note:* In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will find the injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in the scope in which it was declared. The injected-class-name might be less accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which it was declared. — *end note* ] [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> class A { };
> class B : private A { };
> class C : public B {
>   A* p;             // error: injected-class-name A is inaccessible
>   ::A* q;           // OK
> };
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]